# How to avoid unecessary loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a small code with javascript to show the opening hours of the store. Here is the website: https://tsigaradiko.com .

[image: opening]

I used a static div with the text inside (hidden), and using a javascript i make it visible depending on the opening hours of the store like the code below:The problem with this is that if you click on a different link on the top, you can see in just a few miliseconds that both  images are also appreared, before displaying the proper image (close or open). Is there a way to prevent that with a small preloader icon ?

```
 <!-- HTML -->

    <span   class=" open3 "><span class="zin" > <img title="Our shops are now open!" 
           src="https://tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/images/open-sign.png">
      </span></span>
    <span  id="closed" class=" closed3" <span class="zin" >
<img title="Our shops are now closed!"  
     src="https://tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/images/closed-sign.png"> 
       </span>
       <script>   
    //js
    var da = new Date(Date.now()); //days

     var month = new Date();  //month
     var date = new Date(); //date

    if (da.getDay() === 0) { //sunday, Tsigaradiko is closed
      $(".closed3").show();
      $(".open3").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Set them both as `display:none` in the css. Then when the JavaScript will run, it will show the proper image.

```css
.open3, .closed3 {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->

<span class="open3">
  <span class="zin"> 
    <img title="Our shops are now open!" src="https://tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/images/open-sign.png">
  </span>
</span>
<span  id="closed" class="closed3">
  <span class="zin">
    <img title="Our shops are now closed!" src="https://tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/images/closed-sign.png"> 
  </span>
</span>
<script>   
  //js
  var da = new Date(Date.now()); //days

  var month = new Date();  //month
  var date = new Date(); //date

  if (da.getDay() === 0) { //sunday, Tsigaradiko is closed
    $(".closed3").show();
  }
  else{
    $(".open3").show();
  }
</script>
```